# Most used vs mostly used

Tags: word-usage

The most used word by American teenager is Swag. 
Vs 
The mostly used by American teenagers is swag.

Which one is grammatically correct ? Please tell me

Comment: Which do you think it is? Most is an adjective and superlative. Mostly is an adverb. What you say is mostly true [adverb]. The most used word [superlative].

Answer (score 1):

> The most-used word (by American teenagers) is "swag".

The hyphen causes "most-used" to be treated as a single adjective.  You can see this in phrases like "a two-year-old child", "like-minded individuals", or the song "Fat-Bottomed Girls".

And I do agree that "by American teenagers" sounds a bit awkward in the middle like that.  "The word used most often by American teenagers is 'swag'."

Answer (score 0):

The most used word by American teenagers is Swag. Vs The mostly used [word] by American teenagers is swag.

1) The most used word by x is y. Or: The word most used by x is y. OK

2) The word swag, mostly used by American teenagers, is [whatever]. The way it is written in the question is wrong.

The most used = is the superlative, the most used word.

mostly used-mostly is an adverb that modifies used. For example, this word is mostly used by truck drivers.

Mostly used  could be used in other ways also.